# IntelliJ - module not found: java.xml.ws.annotation

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, build

Project has Gradle 5 (gradle-5.0-milestone-1), Java 11 (OpenJDK11) and latest IntelliJ Professional.

With `sourceCompatibility = 10` in gradle.properties it builds/runs tests, but with `sourceCompatibility = 11` it shows 
`module not found: java.xml.ws.annotation`

Note that If I run `test` task from Gradle it runs everything successfully but it only fails when running directly from IntelliJ (pointing on method, right click and run).

Does anyone have any idea what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For those who run into similar problem. Removing `.idea` folder and reimporting whole project helped.

Answer (score 0):

Add to gradle

```
compile group: 'javax.xml.ws', name: 'jaxws-api', version: '2.3.1'
compile 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-osgi:2.4.0-b180830.0438'
compile group: 'com.sun.xml.ws', name: 'jaxws-ri', version: '2.3.1', ext: 'pom'

compile group: 'com.sun.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-impl', version: '2.4.0-b180830.0438'
```

Comment: Doesn't help. Still the same.

Comment: Well, I had similiar error for Java 11. Does it work when you (temporary) switch to Oracle? If it helps, we can narrow down the problem to OpenJDK.

Comment: Didn't work. I have checked your latest changes to comment and it's still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please verify that you don't have `'--add-modules', 'java.xml.ws.annotation'` in your build.gradle, because this module was removed in JDK11, but is still needed for JDK 10.
https://jaxenter.com/jdk-11-java-ee-modules-140674.html