# wsimport task fails when xnocompile is set to false in gradle intellij using Open JDK 11

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, wsdl

My gradle task fails with the below error  when i set **xnocompile**  to false for my **wsimport** task

```
> Task :external-easylink-provider:generateJavaClasses FAILED
[ant:wsimport] parsing WSDL...
[ant:wsimport]
[ant:wsimport]
[ant:wsimport]
[ant:wsimport] Generating code...
[ant:wsimport]
[ant:wsimport]
[ant:wsimport] Compiling code...
[ant:wsimport]
[ant:wsimport] error: module not found: java.xml.ws
[ant:wsimport] 1 error
[ant:wsimport] compilation failed, errors should have been reported
```

below is my gradle task

```
task generateJavaClasses {
    System.setProperty('javax.xml.accessExternalSchema', 'all')
    def jaxbTargetDir = file("$buildDir/generated/classes/wsdl")
    def jaxbsrcdir = file("$buildDir/generated/sources/wsdl")
    doLast {
        jaxbTargetDir.mkdirs()
        jaxbsrcdir.mkdirs()
        ant.taskdef(
                name: 'wsimport',
                classname: 'com.sun.tools.ws.ant.WsImport',
                classpath: configurations.jaxb.asPath
        )
        ant.jaxbTargetDir = jaxbTargetDir
        ant.wsimport(
                keep:true,
                destdir: jaxbTargetDir,
                sourcedestdir: jaxbsrcdir,
                xnocompile: false,
                wsdl:"${projectDir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/mywsdl.wsdl",
                package: "com.mypackage.ws"

        )
    }
}
```

the same task works with JDK 8 but fails with **OPenJDK 11**. Could  someone please help me with this?

Comment: Does it work if you build it by Gradle from command line? Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/q/52831624/2000323 ?

Comment: no it doesn't work